# Sql query with an OR operator between a HAVING and WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Would it be possible to combine a having and a where clause in an OR operator within a single SQL query?

Maybe not the best example, but you'll get the idea:

Select the departments from the employee table that is HR (using the where clause) OR that pays all employees more than 25000 (using the having clause).
So how do we get the OR condition in the query down below? Or would it be better to separate the query into 2 queries.

```
SELECT dept, SUM (salary) 
FROM employee 
WHERE dept = "HR"
GROUP BY dept 
HAVING SUM (salary) > 25000
```

Comment: You can put multiple conditions in the where clause as long as the columns being put in the having clause are a part of the select query .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below will work - you do not have to specify an aggregate in the HAVING clause

```
SELECT dept, SUM (salary) 
FROM employee 
GROUP BY dept 
HAVING dept = "HR" or SUM (salary) > 25000
```

But your statement "that pays all employees more than 25000 "  is not clear. Do you want

Departments where all employees earn over 25000 each, or
departments where all employees earn over 25000 in total?

The query above gives you the second option, as that is closest to your original query

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the `GROUP BY` part up in a derived table. Then apply the conditions to its result:

```
select dept, salarysum
from
(
    SELECT dept, SUM (salary) as salarysum
    FROM employee 
    GROUP BY dept
) dt
where salarysum > 25000 or dept = "HR"
```

Or, perhaps, *"that pays all employees more than 25000"*, means that no dept employee earns less than 25000?

```
select dept, minsalary
from
(
    SELECT dept, MIN(salary) as minsalary
    FROM employee 
    GROUP BY dept
) dt
where minsalary > 25000 or dept = "HR"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want dept where all salaries are over 25000.

```
drop table if exists employees;
create table employees(id int auto_increment primary key, dept varchar(2), salary int);

insert into employees (dept,salary)
values
('HR',10000),('aa',10000),('aa',45000),('bb',25000),('cc',26000),('cc',26000);

select dept,sum(salary) sumsalary,count(*) obs, sum(case when salary > 25000 then 1 else 0 end) over25000
from employees
group by dept having obs = over25000 or dept = 'hr'

+------+-----------+-----+-----------+
| dept | sumsalary | obs | over25000 |
+------+-----------+-----+-----------+
| cc   |     52000 |   2 |         2 |
| HR   |     10000 |   1 |         0 |
+------+-----------+-----+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```